# The formulation of a regular expression for multiple lines

Tags: regex

I have an input text from which I would like to separate specific pattern. I heard that best way is to use regex. I was trying to write it by my own, but I can do it only for a single line and the text that I want to separate consist of multiple line.
Quotes destroy the structure of the text, or I don't know how to do it properly. I want to separate 4 lines
1st line
`.*\b(grabi|atakuje).*`
2nd line
`\((.+)\|(.+)\).*\bBohater`
3th line
`\bJednostki.*[?]`
4th line
`\bPrzybeda.*[0-2][0-3]+:[0-5][0-9]+:[0-5][0-9]`

I have no idea how should I do this using just one regex formula.

Example input text

> Oddziały przychodzące (16)
>
> > ►► LOCKDOWN ◄◄    Respect grabi osadę Laszram
> > ‭(‭−‭23‬‬|‭−‭20‬‬)‬ Legionista  Pretorianin Centurion   Equites legati  Equites imperatoris Equites caesaris    Taran   Ognista katapulta   Konsul  Osadnik Bohater
> > Jednostki   ?   ?   ?   ?   ?   ?   ?   ?   ?   ?   ?
> > Przybędą    w 0:03:30 godz.o 00:21:33
> > ★★Covid - 20 PRO★★  Respect grabi osadę Laszram
> > ‭(‭−‭66‬‬|‭−‭69‬‬)‬ Legionista  Pretorianin Centurion   Equites legati  Equites imperatoris Equites caesaris    Taran   Ognista katapulta   Konsul  Osadnik Bohater
> > Jednostki   ?   ?   ?   ?   ?   ?   ?   ?   ?   ?   ?
> > Przybędą    w 0:10:41 godz.o 00:28:44
> > ★★Covid - 20 PRO★★  Respect grabi osadę Laszram
> > ‭(‭−‭66‬‬|‭−‭69‬‬)‬ Legionista  Pretorianin Centurion   Equites legati  Equites imperatoris Equites caesaris    Taran   Ognista katapulta   Konsul  Osadnik Bohater
> > Jednostki   ?   ?   ?   ?   ?   ?   ?   ?   ?   ?   ?
> > Przybędą    w 0:12:12 godz.o 00:30:15
> >
> > > Oddziały w tej osadzie i jej oazach (1)

Example single output

> ★★Covid - 20 PRO★★ Respect grabi osadę Laszram
> ‭(‭−‭66‬‬|‭−‭69‬‬)‬ Legionista  Pretorianin Centurion   Equites legati  Equites imperatoris Equites caesaris    Taran   Ognista katapulta   Konsul  Osadnik Bohater
> Jednostki   ?   ?   ?   ?   ?   ?   ?   ?   ?   ?   ?
> Przybędą    w 0:12:12 godz.o 00:30:15

Comment: I don't know your language and all the situation, but based on the input and the output sample, you could try this /★★.*?\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}/g

Comment: Whether or not multiple lines are even supported depends on the tool you are using. Please review the [Stack Overflow `regex` tag info page](/tags/regex/info) and [edit] your question to provide more details about your platform and input.

Answer (score 1):

You can join these patterns using `\r?\n` CRLF/LF line break sequence pattern:

```js
.*\b(?:grabi|atakuje).*\r?\n.*\([^()]*\|[^()]*\).*\bBohater.*\r?\nJednostki[ \t?]*\r?\nPrzybędą.*[0-2][0-3]:[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/sO4jGV/2).

Make sure you use `.*` where you do not know what type of text you need to match, it will match any zero or more chars.

**Explanation**:

- `.*` - any 0+ non-linebreak chars, as many as possible
- `\b(?:grabi|atakuje)` - `grabi` or `atakuje` with a word boundary at the start
- `.*\r?\n.*` - any 0+ non-linebreak chars, as many as possible, a CRLF or LF ending, and then again any 0+ non-linebreak chars, as many as possible
- `\([^()]*\|[^()]*\)` - `(`, then 0+ chars other than `(` and `)`, then `|`, again any zero or more chars other than `(` and `_` and a `)`
- `.*` - any 0+ non-linebreak chars, as many as possible
- `\bBohater` - the word `Bohater`
- `.*\r?\n` - any 0+ non-linebreak chars, as many as possible and a CRLF or LF ending
- `Jednostki` - the string `Jednostki`
- `[ \t?]*` - zero or more spaces, tabs and question marks
- `\r?\n` - a CRLF or LF ending
- `Przybędą` - a literal word
- `.*` - any 0+ non-linebreak chars, as many as possible
- `[0-2][0-3]:` - a digit from `0-2` range and a digit from `0-3` range  and a colon
- `[0-5][0-9]:` - a digit from `0-5` range and then any 1 digit and a colon
- `[0-5][0-9]` - a digit from `0-5` range and then any 1 digit